# Why the object is not getting modified when passing the callable object with reference to async

Tags: c++, c++11

Since we are passing the object by reference to std::async, it will call the operator () on same object, then why its member variable is not getting updated

```
struct Y
{
    int m_val;
    Y():m_val(0){}
    double operator()(double val)
    {
        m_val = val*val;
        return m_val;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Y y;
    auto f=std::async(std::ref(y),2);
    cout <<"Returned value " << f.get() << ", Modified value " << y.m_val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output-

```
Returned value 4, Modified value 0
```

As per my understanding it should have called y(2) so y.m_val should be updated to 4, however it is printed as 0 in output. Please clarify what am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++17, the evaluation of arguments to `<<` was unsequenced. That means you have no guarantee that `f.get()` would be called before `y.m_val`'s value is taken.

As a consequence, your program has a potential data race, and therefore *undefined behavior*.

Since C++17, the evaluation order is specified as left-to-right, and so the result you expect is guaranteed.

---

For C++11/14 you can fix this by separating the output statement into multiple statements:

```
std::cout << "Returned value " << f.get();
std::cout << ", Modified value " << y.m_val << endl;
```

or even by calling `f.get()` in a separate statement before the output (storing the result to a variable), which is generally a good idea anyway if your call has side effects.